# Problem accessing /WEB-INF/views/allemployees.jsp. Reason: /WEB-INF/views/allemployees.jsp

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Error que no logro descifrar, lo he buscado durante algún tiempo pero me sale que es el acomodo del documento en la carpeta

> HTTP ERROR 404
>
> ```
> Problem accessing /WEB-INF/views/allemployees.jsp. Reason:
>
>     /WEB-INF/views/allemployees.jsp
> Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.4.v20151007
> ```

Comment: Sería bueno que publicases el stacktrace o mensaje de error completo que tienes en tu consola. Por favor, hazlo como texto y no como imagen.

Comment: Listo, he puesto el mensaje como texto

Comment: Al parecer estás intentando acceder allí directamente desde tu navegador, ¿cierto? Pues no podrás hacerlo así puesto que la carpeta WEB-INF no es visible desde un navegador. Lo que necesitas hacer es tener un servlet que realice un forward a esta vista.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!